# Arabic characters always null in oracledb nodejs update query

Tags: node.js, plsql, node-oracledb, node-oracle

i am running query in oracle db with nodejs as

```
await executeQuery(connection, updateStatusQueryFail, {
    status: "unmatched",
    iban: iban,
    NID_MISMATCH: mismatches['nid'],
    PASSPORT_MISMATCH: mismatches['passport_number'],
    PHONE_MISMATCH: mismatches['phone'],
  });
```

`mismatches.passport_number` has arabic values in it and the above query is mapped to

```
const updateStatusQueryFail = `UPDATE DIGX_CZ_CBL_FCMS_ACCOUNT_LIST
 SET STATE = :status,
 NID_MISMATCH = :NID_MISMATCH,
 PASSPORT_MISMATCH = :PASSPORT_MISMATCH,
 PHONE_MISMATCH = :PHONE_MISMATCH,
 UPDATED_AT= SYSDATE
 WHERE IBAN = :iban`;
```

the weird part is, it does not work when I try it like this

```
await executeQuery(connection, updateStatusQueryFail, {
    status: "unmatched",
    iban: iban,
    NID_MISMATCH: mismatches['nid'],
    PASSPORT_MISMATCH: mismatches['passport_number'],
    PHONE_MISMATCH: mismatches['phone'],
  });
```

but works when I try it like

```
await executeQuery(connection, updateStatusQueryFail, {
    status: "unmatched",
    iban: iban,
    NID_MISMATCH: mismatches['nid'],
    PASSPORT_MISMATCH:  'يجب أن يحتوي النص رقم جواز السفر على 8 حروفٍ/حرفًا بالظبط'
    PHONE_MISMATCH: mismatches['phone'],
  });
```

I am using node 20 vesion, with oracledb driver. Any help would be highly appreciated. Oh yeah no error is thrown.

Almost spent 4-6 hours already.

Comment: I can deduce that `mismatches['passport_number']` is a different string from the actual Arabic value, but then I can't see how `mismatches` was defined.

Comment: nope. it has the Arabic value in it. This is how I a defining it

`mismatches['passport_number'] = 'يجب أن يحتوي النص رقم جواز السفر على 8 حروفٍ/حرفًا بالظ'`

Comment: Something else may be overwriting it. Or there may be some invisible characters so you may want to check the code points like `your_string.split('').map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0))`. In any case, for `executeQuery(connection, updateStatusQueryFail, your_object)`, if `your_object` is exactly same, the result should be the same.

Comment: nope, I ended up using knex.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `oracledb` configuration in your Node.js application. You may need to set the `oracledb.fetchAsString` property to handle strings with special characters. And also, check that the `NLS_LANG` environment variable is set correctly.

```
oracledb.fetchAsString = [oracledb.CLOB];
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```

lastly, check that your Oracle database and Node.js application are using the same character set and collation. Arabic characters may require a specific character set to be handled correctly.

Comment: Oh sorry that's by mistake while I was tying it here. comma is already there in my code. I will update my question

Comment: I have edited it, may be it helps!

Comment: `oracledb.fetchAsString` won't affect special characters; it has a different purpose which is to reduce lines of code needed to access the fetched data. Setting the character set in NLS_LANG has no effect: node-oracledb always uses UTF-8 as the client character set.